# Find And Replace Current Text to Wrap In Color

Tags: bash, sed, colors, zsh

So I'm trying to make an alias for `cal` that will run it through `sed` to wrap the current day in the terminal escapes for red.

```
cal | sed "s/($(date +%d))/\\033\[94m$(date +%d)\\033\[0m/g"
```

However, I apparently can't use inline command execution like `$(date +%d)` inside of a capture group.

In addition, if I use the command substitution in both place, I can get the replacement to work, but not the backslashes to escape the color code.

```
$ cal | sed "s/$(date +%d)/\\033\[94m$(date +%d)\\033\[0m/g"
      May 2016
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 033[94m11033[0m 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31
```

Is there a way to wrap a replacement in colors? In addition, is there a better regex to handle single digit days? (Since on the first through ninth days of the month, it will highlight every instance of that number on the calendar.)

EDIT: I'm running OS X, Darwin Kernel Version 15.2.0, since apparently the cal implementation on OS X doesn't support the `-h` option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
cal -h | sed "s/$(date +%d)/"$'\033\[94m&\033\[0m/g'
```

Notes:

1. By default, `cal` highlights the current day.  I used the `-h` option to turn that off so it doesn't interfere with your preferred color. [Update: apparently this applies to GNU `cal` only]
2. You are right that `$(date +%d)` has to appear in double-quotes.  The rest of the command, however, does not.  Above, I used bash's `$'...'` for the rest of the command because it supports escape sequences.
3. There is no need for a second `$(date +%d)`.  We can recall the matched text with `&`.
4. If you have GNU sed, a convenient way to fix the single-digit day issue is to require the matched text to be a whole word using `\<...\>`:

   ```
   cal -h | sed "s/\<$(date +%d)\>/"$'\033\[94m&\033\[0m/g'  # GNU
   ```

   If your sed does not have that feature, you will need to `s` commands:

   ```
   cal -h | sed "s/ $(date +%d) /"$'\033\[94m&\033\[0m/g; '"s/ $(date +%d)$/"$'\033\[94m&\033\[0m/g'
   ```

   The first substitute command looks for the date surrounded by spaces.  This works for all single digit dates except the ones at the end of a line.  The second looks for dates preceded by a space and followed by the end of the line (`$`).

Comment: Apparently the OS X version of cal doesn't support the -h option, and does not highlight by default. I'll give this one a shot. Also, I learned a few new features about `bash` and `sed` thanks to this :)

Comment: Apparently it's something wrong with the coloring I'm using. I copied the colors from a script I was using as a pre-commit hook, written in python, but simply echoing out `\033[94m11\033[0m` returns an uncolored 11. Might be my iterm profile

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi Under my xterm(linux), it produces a purple.  If I change the 94 to 92, it produces green.  (If I had access to OSX, I would test it there but, unfortunately,  I don't.)

Comment: I managed to isolate 91 as red according to my profile. (Might be a bit messed up as it's a heavily modified solarized profile) Looks like that fixes the issue. :P All this finagling, and it mainly came down to a busted color profile. Looks like OS X's sed implementation doesn't support the `<>` word boundaries.